# Laravel unique validation with where and join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

I'm trying to add aditional where clause in the unique validation rule. But before that, i need a join with other table. But I'm not being successful.

I have 2 Tables:

### teams

with id, and name field

### role_user_team

with role_id, user_id, and team_id being this three the key.

So i need to check if the teams.name field is unique for one specific user.
I did try this:

```
'name' => Rule::unique('teams')->where(function ($query){
    //return $query->where('account_id', 1);
    return $query->join('role_user', 'role_user.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')->where('role_user', Auth::user()->id);
          });
```

I know the problem is with the join but i don´t know how to solve it.
Thank you!

Comment: Use `Auth::id()` instead of `Auth::user()->id`. Object `Auth::user()` can not exists.

Comment: I think join is not allowed in the where clause...so i need a new validation rule to check what i want. ¿Any idea of this?

Comment: Indeed, seems like joining is not functioning, although this is not documented anywhere. The closure gets a standard query builder object so you would expect joining to just work. But the querybuilder object seems to get edited afterwards, breaking joins.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in how Laravel handles the QueryBuilder object just before the actual query to DB is done. Printing the query log shows that **no actual join is performed**. It could also be an inadequacy in the [documentation (under "additional where clauses")](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique), because that doesn't mention a limitation on using the QueryBuilder.

The quickest solution is to extend the Validator on the fly, like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    Validator::extend('custom_rule', function ($attribute, $value) {
        // The user that's being edited, if any.
        $currentUser = $this->route('user');

        $query = User::join('addresses', function ($join) {
            $join->on('addresses.user_id', 'users.id')
                ->where('addresses.address_type', 'home');
        })->where($attribute, $value)->where('users.id', '!=', $currentUser->id ?? 0);

        // True means pass, false means fail validation.
        // If count is 0, that means the unique constraint passes.
        return !$query->count();
    });

    return [
        'name' => 'required|custom_rule',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. Face the same problem and fix it like this:

```
'name' => Rule::unique('teams')->where(function ($query){
    //return $query->where('account_id', 1);
    $query->join('role_user', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('role_user.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')->where('role_user', Auth::user()->id);
       });
     })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works like charm! thanks... and it's not about the return statement either

Comment: @EmekeAjeh bkm Which version are you using ? Am using 5.5 doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir I was using v8. V5.5 is a lot older so might be missing some method or have different syntax. If you could verify the source code from ./vendor directory and see what's missing or different, that might help.

Comment: Yep, I resort to using [Rule Object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#using-rule-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.8 - problem is still exists.

See \Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier class, method addConditions().

It can be clearly seen that if a validation rule condition is a closure, then it is performed inside the nested where section, which excludes the possibility of using joins:

```
/**
 * Add the given conditions to the query.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  $query
 * @param  array  $conditions
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
protected function addConditions($query, $conditions)
{
    foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
        if ($value instanceof Closure) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($value) {
                $value($query);
            });
        } else {
            $this->addWhere($query, $key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```

And yes, the only one way to use join in validation rule - is make your own rule, like aross sayd.

Answer (score -1):

[Look at the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) in **Advanced Join Clauses**

```
$query->join('role_user', function ($join) {
    return $join->on('role_user.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')->on('role_user', '=', Auth::id());
});
```